# When Debugging C# why can you not change the count of a dictionary key value pair?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

When debugging in C# you can view values in the Locals window, by default my database has 2 values, yet I Need to test with 4.

[image]

is there a way to change the count to 4

Edit: I can not change the Database as it will make the application worse

Comment: Use the immediate window to add two more values.

Comment: @ amy could you give a rough example?

Comment: Add two more items in your DB test data?  After all, if the *test* is what would happen when there are 4 values in the DB, then shouldn't there be 4 values in the DB?  Otherwise you're not really testing that scenario.

Comment: Type into your immediate window the same line of code used to add a value in the dictionary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the immediate window, just type something like:

```
dictionary.Add("some_key", "some_value");
dictionary.Add("some_key2", "some_value2");
```

Comment: This wouldn't even compile, the `Add` method takes 2 parameters, a key and a value. So it would be `dictionary.Add("some_key", "some_value");`

Comment: @DavidG Thank you for notice.